# How to determine the time take by PCA in weka?

Tags: weka

As I'm a mathematician, I'd like to know the time taken by the PCA to perform the reduction. I'd like to determine the time taken in seconds as we do it using tic toc in Matlab.

Comment: Are you using Weka programmatically or through the GUI?

Comment: I'm using weka GUI

Comment: Hm i dont really know if weka GUI supports this. Maybe you should ask to WEKA's list